# how to show preview on hover of video

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video-streaming, videogular

I am loading multiple video in a web page using AngularJs using Videogular, an HTML5 video player for AngularJS.

I need to show the preview of a video on hover, something like like moving images I have seen in many website. I can't play orignal video because it will take lots of time to load since there are more than 500 video per page.

Comment: http://ronallo.com/blog/a-plugin-for-mediaelement-js-for-preview-thumbnails-on-hover-over-the-time-rail/ maybe  it will help you

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly in that you want to to show a preview of a linked video when hovering over a thumbnail of it? Can you link to the relevant part or show us the code and how it looks?